# How do I connect to a TFS datasource in Report Builder hosted on xxx.VisualStudio.com

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, reportbuilder3.0

We have a TFS hosted on {tenant}.visualstudio.com

I'd like to create some reports.  I know the url, username and password but when I enter it nothing comes up in the list of Databases.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VSO there is no analysis cube and data warehouse. That said there is extensive restfull API's that you can use to get data out. In fact you should be able to get more data.

There is full documentation for the API: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/reference/reference-vso-overview-vsi.aspx

I do not believe that SSRS supports Rest.

All modern charting controls can consume this data so it is as simple as creating a new webpage, adding a charting component from NuGet, and pulling the data.